# Range of values for $\frac{\langle f | \mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma |f \rangle}{\langle f | f \rangle}$, with $|\mathbf n| = 1$?

Tags: inner-products, mathematical-physics, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds, hermitian-matrices

I'm trying to find the range of possible values for the expression

$$w := \frac{\langle f | \mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma |f \rangle}{\langle f | f \rangle},$$

where $\mathbf n \in \mathbb R^3$, $|\mathbf n| = 1$, $| f \rangle \in \mathbb C^2$, and $\langle f| := | f \rangle^\dagger$ is the hermitian conjugate of $| f \rangle$. The expression $\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma$ is physics shorthand for $\sum_{i=1}^3 n_i \sigma_i$, where the $\sigma_i$ are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Note that the Pauli matrices are hermitian, and hence $w \in \mathbb R$.

Alternatively I could settle for just the bounds on $w^2$. There is a bunch of useful identities for the Pauli matrices, but I haven't been able to get much out of them in this case. The most progress I've had is

$$
\begin{split}
\langle f | f \rangle^2 w^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \langle f | n_i \sigma_i | f \rangle \langle f | n_j \sigma_j | f \rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 n_i^2 \langle f | \sigma_i | f \rangle^2 + \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \ne i}}^3 n_i n_j \langle f | \sigma_i | f \rangle \langle f | \sigma_j | f \rangle \\
&\le \langle f | f \rangle^2 + \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \ne i}}^3 n_i n_j \langle f | \sigma_i | f \rangle \langle f | \sigma_j | f \rangle,
\end{split}
$$

using $n_i^2 \le 1$ and the easily verifiable fact that $\sum_{i=1}^3 \langle f | \sigma_i | f \rangle^2 = \langle f | f \rangle^2$. But I'm not sure how useful this form is, because I'm not making much headway with that final sum.

Is there a neat way to find the range of possible values for $w$, or at least bounds for $w^2$? I feel like there should be, but I'm not quite getting there. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the range of values for $w$ is $[-1,1]$.

The problem can be significantly simplified using the [adjoint action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Adjoint_action) of elements of $SU(2)$ on Pauli vectors. The adjoint action $g^{-1}(\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma)g$ of an element $g\in SU(2)$ on a Pauli vector $\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma$ corresponds to a rotation of $\mathbf n$ (with each rotation in $O(3)$ corresponding to two elements of $SU(2)$ with opposite signs).

That means that we don’t have to vary $f$ and $\mathbf n$ independently, since a change from $f$ to $gf$ can be replaced by a change from $\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma$ to $g^{-1}(\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma)g$. Thus we can fix $\mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma=\sigma_1=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ and only vary $f$. Moreover, since the expression of interest is normalized with $\langle f|f\rangle$, we only need to consider unit vectors $f$ with $\langle f|f\rangle=1$; also, multiplying $f$ by a phase factor $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ leaves the expression invariant.

With $f=\pmatrix{a\\b}$, we have

$$
w=\pmatrix{a^*&b^*}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{a\\b}=a^*b+b^*a=2\mathfrak{Re}(a^*b)\;.
$$

This can be made $0$ by making $a^*b$ imaginary, and for any $w\gt0$ we can obtain the corresponding value $-w$ by replacing $b$ by $-b$; also, $w$ is continuous in $a$ and $b$, so the range of values of $w$ is of the form $[-x,x]$. To obtain the maximal value $x$, $a$ and $b$ need to be in phase, e.g. both real; then since $f$ is a unit vector we can parametrize it by $\pmatrix{\cos\phi\\\sin\phi}$. The maximum is attained at $\phi=\frac\pi4$, i.e. $f=\frac1{\sqrt2}\pmatrix{1\\1}$, where $w=1$.

Comment: Wonderfull answer! $[-1, 1]$ was exactly what I suspected (and hoped!) it would be, from the application where it came up. I also suspected there should be a lot of symmetry, but did not have the necessary knowledge to do what you have done here. I guess I should study more group- and representation theory to learn this stuff? (I've only had a little bit in a "group theory for physicists" type course.)

Comment: @ummg: Yes, you should :-) I also studied physics. I learned some of my group theory and representation theory from [Sternberg](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01LWN8XBM/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) – if I remember correctly he has quite a bit on $SU(2)$ and $O(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at this question after some time I realize that there is a very simple way to see that the range of values for $w$ is $[-1,1]$. One only has to notice that $w$ is a [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) with a Hermitian matrix. It is well-known that a Rayleigh quotient

$$R_M(|x\rangle) = \frac{\langle x| M |x\rangle}{\langle x|x\rangle}$$

has range $[\lambda_\text{min}, \lambda_\text{max}]$ when $M$ is Hermitian, where $\lambda_\text{min}$ and $\lambda_\text{max}$ are the least and greatest eigenvalues of $M$, respectively. The proof is simple and proceeds by expressing $|x\rangle$ in the eigenbasis of $M$.

For the specific case $M = \mathbf n \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma$, with $\mathbf n$ being real and unit length, it is easy to compute the eigenvalues $\pm 1$ directly, and the result follows.